# Como realizar conexão persistente utilizando WebSocket e um servidor Socket Delphi?

Tags: javascript, delphi

Estou tentando criar uma comunicação via *WebSocket* com um servidor socket Delphi,

1º Passo, `readystate` 0 - Server recebe o header do WebSocket.

2º Passo, `readystate` 3 - Já vai para desconectado.

**Javascript:**

```
var host = 'ws://10.1.1.10:8100'; // SET THIS TO YOUR SERVER
socketWebservice = new WebSocket(host);

socketWebservice.onopen = function(msg) {
  socketWebservice.send('LOGON');
  alert('entrou');
  //setIntSocketSend = setInterval('contSendSocket()', 119000); //confere o Login a cada 4m:58s
};
socketWebservice.onmessage = function(msg) {
  on_socket_get(msg.data);
};
socketWebservice.onclose = function(msg) {
  //            clearInterval(setIntSocketSend);
  console.log(msg);
};
```

O Delphi utiliza o componente **TServerSocket**.

**Código do Servidor:**

```
unit uServidor;

interface

uses System.Win.ScktComp, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Controls, System.Classes, Vcl.Forms,
     System.SysUtils;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ServerSocket1: TServerSocket;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    EdtPorta: TEdit;
    Label2: TLabel;
    BtnConectar: TButton;
    ckTodos: TCheckBox;
    EdtMensagem: TMemo;
    procedure BtnConectarClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject;
      Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
      Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject;
      Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  private
    procedure Reconectar;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.BtnConectarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ServerSocket1.Port   := StrToInt(EdtPorta.Text);
  try
    ServerSocket1.Active := true;
    BtnConectar.Caption  := 'Conectado';
    BtnConectar.Enabled  := false;
  except
    raise;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  I : Integer;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;
  for I := 0 to Pred(ServerSocket1.Socket.ActiveConnections) do
    ListBox1.Items.Add('['+ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[I].RemoteAddress+']');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I : Integer;
begin
  if ckTodos.Checked then
    for I := 0 to Pred(ListBox1.Items.Count) do
      ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[I].SendText(EdtMensagem.Lines.Text)
  else
    ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[ListBox1.ItemIndex].SendText(EdtMensagem.Lines.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  EdtMensagem.TEXT := Socket.ReceiveText;
end;

procedure TForm1.Reconectar;
begin
  ServerSocket1.Active := false;
  ServerSocket1.Active := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  I : Integer;
  Endereco : String;
begin
  for I := 0 to Pred(ListBox1.Items.Count) do
  begin
    Endereco := '['+Socket.RemoteAddress+']';
    if Endereco = ListBox1.Items.Strings[I] then
    begin
      ListBox1.Items.Strings[I] := ListBox1.Items.Strings[I] + ' - DESCONECTADO';
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Bom dia. Você pode por favor especificar de maneira mais clara qual a sua dúvida? Até onde você conseguiu chegar? Está enfrentando algum problema? Qual versão do Delphi você está usando?

Comment: Utilizo a versão do delphi xe4, para a conexão o componente TserverSocket. 
1. Ativo o servidor para a porta "8100". 
2. Tento me conectar pelo WebSocket na porta "8100", visualizo o "readyState" do WebSocket ele fica no "0 - CONNECTING".
3. No sevirdor recebo o cabeçalho da conexão WebSocket. 
4. No WebSocket continua "0 - CONNECTING" por alguns segundos e logo depois ja passa para "3 - CLOSED", não passa para o "readyState" "1 - OPEN".

Comment: Essas portas estão abertas no firewall? O código do server nos ajudaria nesta questão.

Comment: Não é firewall,  postei o código do server.

Comment: O que pode ajudar é ver qual o erro que está ocorrendo na conexão. Tente implementar o código a seguir no WebSocket `let $connectionError = document.getElementById("connection-error");

setTimeout( () => {
  if (ws.readyState !== 1) {
    $connectionError.classList.add( "show" );
  }
}, 100 );`  O código foi extraído do link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546424/how-to-wait-for-a-websockets-readystate-to-change]

Comment: Não deu certo, isto ai é apenas para mostrar a mensagem de erro, e ela continua vindo status 0 e 3

Comment: Não sei muito de delphy mas, websocket, pelo que sei, é uma camada em cima de http e, pelo pouco que entendi do código, me parece que você está usando um socketserver normal. Isso é confirmado pelo comportamento no lado cliente: Ele entra em connecting, porém, não consegue concluir a negociação http então desconecta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema do `TServerSocket` é que ele é muito Limitado!

Eu atualmente uso  **Socket.IO** uma solução que encontrei no [github](https://github.com/andremussche/DelphiWebsockets).

Usando seu próprio `javascript` postado aqui consegui efetuar a comunicação:

*Rodando o Servidor:*

```
  Server := TIdWebsocketServer.Create(Self);
  Server.DefaultPort := 8200;
  Server.SocketIO.OnEvent(C_CLIENT_EVENT,

  procedure(const ASocket: ISocketIOContext; const aArgument: TSuperArray; const aCallback: ISocketIOCallback)
  begin
    //show request (threadsafe)
    ShowMessageInMainthread('REQUEST: ' + aArgument[0].AsJSon);
    //send callback (only if specified!)
    if aCallback <> nil then
      aCallback.SendResponse( SO(['succes', True]).AsJSon );
  end);

  Server.Active      := True;
```

*Mandando mensagem:*

```
server.SendMessageToAll('Enviado do Delphi via Socket!');
```

Comment: Então o problema era no meu componente, jurava que era no js, testei aqui é rodou, valeu!